not getting expected output while using "some" in update query
When I try to fetch the server whose members store the relation with logged in user, it gives null as output, even though there exits a server (I verified it using console.log()).
This is the way it is supposed to be done:
const server = await db.server.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: params.serverId,
      members: {
        some: {
          profileId: profile.id
        }
      }
    }
  });

  if (!server) {
    return redirect("/");
  }

and this is how, i have implemented it
    const server = await db.server.findUnique({
        where: {
            id: params.serverId,
        }
    });

    const member = await db.member.findFirst({
        where: {
          AND: [
            { profileId: profile.id }, 
            { serverId: server?.id }, 
          ]
        }
      });
    if (member === null || !server ) return redirect('/'); 

I want to go with 1st approach but 1st approach is not returning any server while 2nd one is returning the expected output.

The second approach looks like it is querying 2 different collections.  Wouldn't that require a join or lookup in the first approach?

In first approach, we have used "some" keyword, which checks the membership. This approach is giving me an error "The records for relation MemberToServer between the Server and Member models are not connected, thats why i have used 2nd approach to somehow, replicate the task but i want to solve the error of 1st approach
